# Запрещение move конструктора

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Почему следующий код работает, хотя я явно удалил `move` конструктор?

```
class X {
public:
    X() = default;
    X(const X&) = delete;
    X(X&&) = delete;

    int val = 42;
};

template<typename T>
int foo(T x) {
    return x.val;
}


int main() {
    X x1;
    //X x2{x1}; // error
    //X x3{std::move(x1)}; // error
    //foo(x1); // error
    //foo(std::move(x1)); //error
    foo(X{}); // OK?
}
```

Какие ограничения налагаются на тип `T` кроме того, что он должен иметь member `val`, приводимый к `int`? Можно ли запретить последнюю передачу?

Comment: При использовании С++17 в `foo(X{});` move конструктор не вызывается. Последнюю передачу можно запретить запретив конструктор по-умолчанию. Ну или можно использовать более старые стандарты языка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что в строчке `foo(X{});` нет ни копирования, ни перемещения. Есть материализация prvalue в объект с именем `x`. Материализация, как может быть понятно из самого термина, это прямое создание объекта из prvalue, без каких либо промежуточных копирований/перемещений. Запретить это нельзя, это «вшито» в стандарт C++17.

Подробнее я писал об этом [здесь](http://scrutator.me/post/2018/04/28/cpp17_lang_features_p3.aspx#copy_ellision).

Comment: понял, спасибо, сейчас почитаю